# CSS3 background image doesn't vertically stretch

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with vertically stretching the background image all the way down to the bottom. I'm aware that I can set `height` or `min-height` on the container class `.view-index` but don't want to set height property manually as I want the image to respond to the browser size when users resize the browser.

Whilst the background image stretches down the bottom, I don't want it to cover the second image, `.view-extra img`.

Example of what I would like to achieve: https://mdbootstrap.com/live/_MDB/index/docs/page-layouts/intro-transparent.html

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/julysfx/9ut3wtwf/) (updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the height to 100vh will give you what you need.

```css
.view-index {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/f6f5Xq7.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.view-text {
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="view-index">
    <div class="view-text">
      <h2>This Navbar isn't fixed</h2>
      <h5>When you scroll down it will disappear</h5>
      <br>
      <p>Full page intro with background image will be always regardless of device </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-extra">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0NCooNY.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow struggled so much for such a simple solution. Nice and simple, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
.view-index {
    background: url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/img (42).jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.view-text {
 color: white;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-index">
 <div class="view-text">
  <h2>This Navbar isn't fixed</h2>
  <h5>When you scroll down it will disappear</h5>
  <br>
  <p>Full page intro with background image will be always displayed in full screen mode, regardless of device </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeh that kinda solves the problem but I actually have another div outside of `view-index` (please see updated OP) so I can't really set `position: absolute` on `view-index` as it will overlap the second image `view-extra img`. For now, I will upvote your post as you provided a solution to what I previously wrote in the OP anyway. Thanks.